# Postgres blocking behaviour with concurrency/load

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, load

During decent load - 50 simultaneous users hitting PostgreSQL with simple query but with GIS calculations. The DB shows significant blocking of calls. Std. Dev. starts increasing to 300 ms, from 50 ms when there are 10 simultaneous connections.

Any pointers?

Comment: Is it blocking or just under heavy load? What does `top` show?

Comment: randomly same query starts taking more time, the execution time has higher deviation.

Comment: Well, if the server is under heavy load, that's not unexpected. You'll need to examine what load it is under. Can your server handle 50 concurrent queries? How many cores do you have?

Comment: Sparc-T3 Solaris with 1 cpu, 2 cores, and 16 virtual processors

Comment: So why exactly do you expect to run 50 concurrent queries on 2 cores at the same speed as 2 queries? Write yourself a little test script that forks 50 times and counts to 1 million and see what happens to the spread of times.

Answer (score 0):

In general, one expects to plan concurrency as follows on PostgreSQL at least as a starting point:

twice your physical cores (in this case 2) + your number of hard drive spindles.

Faster storage actually increases concurrency problems in some ways, but the queries run faster and so it decreases them in other ways (i.e. you can run more queries per second, just fewer at the same time at top speed).